# Swift Expected Declaration error? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been learning how to code in Swift and followed some tutorials. While following a tutorial to make a zigzag-like game, I ran into an error that I don't know how to fix.

```
if (y > 720) {
    low = true
}
```

The code above gives me an error `Expected Declaration`.

The following is the rest of my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {

        TapsValid = true
        BallChange = true
        self.GameOver.hidden = true
        self.Retry.hidden = true
        self.Ball.hidden = false
        self.Logo.hidden = true
        self.Play.hidden = true
        self.ScoreBoard.hidden = true

        self.Ball.center.x = 178.0
        self.Ball.center.y = 390.0
        self.Pillar1.center = CGPointMake(175.0 , 436.0)
        self.Pillar2.center = CGPointMake(214.0 , 407.0)

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.045, target: self , selector: Selector("movement"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.Pillar3.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar2.center.x, y: Pillar2.center.y)
        self.Pillar4.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar3.center.x, y: Pillar3.center.y)
        self.Pillar5.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar4.center.x, y: Pillar4.center.y)
        self.Pillar6.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar5.center.x, y: Pillar5.center.y)
        self.Pillar7.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar6.center.x, y: Pillar6.center.y)
        self.Pillar8.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar7.center.x, y: Pillar7.center.y)
        self.Pillar9.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar8.center.x, y: Pillar8.center.y)
        self.Pillar10.center = pillarPlacement(Pillar9.center.x, y: Pillar9.center.y)

        self.Pillar1.hidden = false
        self.Pillar2.hidden = false
        self.Pillar3.hidden = false
        self.Pillar4.hidden = false
        self.Pillar5.hidden = false
        self.Pillar6.hidden = false
        self.Pillar7.hidden = false
        self.Pillar8.hidden = false
        self.Pillar9.hidden = false
        self.Pillar10.hidden = false
        self.PillarTop.hidden = false
        self.PillarTop2.hidden = false
        self.PillarTop3.hidden = false

    }
    @IBAction func Retry(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar10: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar9: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar8: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar7: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar6: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar5: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pillar1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PillarTop3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PillarTop2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PillarTop: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScoreBoard: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Retry: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Logo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var GameOver: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Ball: UIImageView!
    var timer  = NSTimer()
    var TapsValid:Bool?
    var BallRight:Bool?
    var BallChange:Bool?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.GameOver.hidden = true
        self.Retry.hidden = true
        self.Ball.hidden = true
        self.Logo.hidden = false
        self.Play.hidden = false
        self.ScoreBoard.hidden = true
        self.Pillar1.hidden = true
        self.Pillar2.hidden = true
        self.Pillar3.hidden = true
        self.Pillar4.hidden = true
        self.Pillar5.hidden = true
        self.Pillar6.hidden = true
        self.Pillar7.hidden = true
        self.Pillar8.hidden = true
        self.Pillar9.hidden = true
        self.Pillar10.hidden = true
        self.PillarTop.hidden = true
        self.PillarTop2.hidden = true
        self.PillarTop3.hidden = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if TapsValid == true {
            if BallRight == true {
                BallChange = false
            } else {
                BallChange = true
            }
        }
    }

    func movement() {

        if BallChange == false{
            BallRight = false
        } else {
            BallRight = true
        }
        if BallRight == true {
            Ball.center.x += 6.5
            Ball.center.y -= 0.5
        } else {
            Ball.center.x -= 6.5
            Ball.center.y -= 0.5
        }

        Ball.center.y += 0.5
        Pillar1.center.y += 5
        Pillar2.center.y += 5
        Pillar3.center.y += 5
        Pillar4.center.y += 5
        Pillar5.center.y += 5
        Pillar6.center.y += 5
        Pillar7.center.y += 5
        Pillar8.center.y += 5
        Pillar9.center.y += 5
        Pillar10.center.y += 5

    }

    func movePillarUp(floatx: CGFloat, floaty: CGFloat, pillarNumber: Int) -> (CGPoint) {

        var center = CGPointMake(floatx, floaty)

        if checkPillarPosition(floaty) == true {
            switch pillarNumber{
            case 1:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar10.center.x, y: self.Pillar10.center.y)
                break
            case 2:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar1.center.x, y: self.Pillar2.center.y)
                break
            case 3:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar2.center.x, y: self.Pillar2.center.y)
                break
            case 4:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar3.center.x, y: self.Pillar3.center.y)
                break
            case 5:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar4.center.x, y: self.Pillar4.center.y)
                break
            case 6:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar5.center.x, y: self.Pillar5.center.y)
                break
            case 7:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar6.center.x, y: self.Pillar6.center.y)
                break
            case 8:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar7.center.x, y: self.Pillar7.center.y)
                break
            case 9:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar8.center.x, y: self.Pillar8.center.y)
                break
            case 10:
                center = pillarPlacement(self.Pillar9.center.x, y: self.Pillar9.center.y)
                break
            default:
                break

            }
        }
      return(center)
    }

    func checkPillarPosition(y: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        var low = false}



    if (y > 720) {
    low = true
    }



    //This function moves pillars arround randomally
    func pillarPlacement(x: CGFloat,y: CGFloat) -> (CGPoint) {

        var PillarNewX: CGFloat
        var PillarNewY: CGFloat

        let random: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)


        if random == 1 {

            PillarNewX = x + 39
            PillarNewY = y - 29

            if PillarNewX >= 319 {
                PillarNewX = x - 40
                PillarNewY = y - 30
            }

        } else  {

            PillarNewX = x - 40
            PillarNewY = y - 30

            if PillarNewX <= 17 {
                PillarNewX = x + 39
                PillarNewY = y - 29
            }

        }

        let NewPillarCenter = CGPointMake(PillarNewX, PillarNewY)
        return(NewPillarCenter)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code isn't inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement is not in a function, I think you may want to add it to the checkPillarPosition. The updated code would look like this:

```
    func checkPillarPosition(y: CGFloat) -> Bool {

    var low = false

    if (y > 720) {

    low = true

    return true

    } else {

    return false

    }
    }
```

This would remove your error and would fix your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: wait now its saying "missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'"

Comment: @RobertSmith, Sorry, I updated the code, now it should work fine as you would need return statements in a function. Hope that fixes the problem!

Comment: @RobertSmith, Did that fix your problem? Or is it not the correct answer? If it is the correct answer, you may want to mark it as the correct answer to know that it helped you.

Comment: @RobertSmith, Did it fix your problem?

Comment: yes thank you, would I be able to get in touch with you through Skype to help me out with another problem/improvement in my code?

Comment: @RobertSmith If this did help you, mark it as the correct answer so people know what helped you

Comment: @RobertSmith Can you mark it as the correct answer? As it did help you.